# scroll to next element with same parent class

Tags: jquery, class, scroll

I have several divs with the class name "fullcontent".
In each div I have 2 elements: "fullcontent--prev" and "fullcontent--next".
On click on this elements I want to scroll to the next/previous fullcontent-div.

But I don't get this working with this:

https://jsfiddle.net/whgxauyd/1/

```js
$(".fullcontent--prev").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.fullcontent').nextAll().offset().top
  }, 1000, 'easeInOutSine');
});

$(".fullcontent--next").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.fullcontent').nextAll().offset().top
  }, 1000, 'easeInOutSine');
});
```

```css
.fullcontent {
  z-index: 900;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 100px;

  &--prev {
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  &--next {
    height: 75%;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.55;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<section>

<div class="fullcontent"> 1
  <div class="fullcontent--prev"></div>
  <div class="fullcontent--next"></div>
</div>

<div class="fullcontent"> 2
  <div class="fullcontent--prev"></div>
  <div class="fullcontent--next"></div>
</div>

<div class="fullcontent"> 3
  <div class="fullcontent--prev"></div>
  <div class="fullcontent--next"></div>
</div>

<div class="fullcontent"> 4
  <div class="fullcontent--prev"></div>
  <div class="fullcontent--next"></div>
</div>

</section>
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to target specific clicked element's parent. You could use in your case `$(this).closest('.fullcontent')`.

Your code becomes:

```
$(".fullcontent--prev").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).closest('.fullcontent').prevAll().offset().top
  }, 1000, 'easeInOutSine');
});

$(".fullcontent--next").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).closest('.fullcontent').nextAll().offset().top
  }, 1000, 'easeInOutSine');
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/whgxauyd/2/)

Answer (score 0):

you were not saving the reference to the current element focused 
just add the reference like `var elementCur=$(this).parent();`  for `next` and `var curElement=$(this).parent()` for `prev` like below

```
$(".fullcontent--prev").on('click',function() {
var curElement=$(this).parent();
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: curElement.prevAll().offset().top
  }, 1000, 'easeInOutSine');
});

$(".fullcontent--next").on('click',function() {

var elementCur=$(this).parent();
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: elementCur.nextAll().offset().top
  }, 1000, 'easeInOutSine');
});
```

See Demo

```js
$(".fullcontent--prev").on('click', function() {
  var curElement = $(this).parent();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: curElement.prevAll().offset().top
  }, 1000, 'easeInOutSine');
});

$(".fullcontent--next").on('click', function() {

  var elementCur = $(this).parent();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: elementCur.nextAll().offset().top
  }, 1000, 'easeInOutSine');
});
```

```css
.fullcontent {
  z-index: 900;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  &--prev {
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  &--next {
    height: 75%;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.55;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<section>

  <div class="fullcontent"> 1
    <div class="fullcontent--prev">Prev</div>
    <div class="fullcontent--next">Next</div>
  </div>

  <div class="fullcontent"> 2
    <div class="fullcontent--prev">Prev</div>
    <div class="fullcontent--next">Next</div>
  </div>

  <div class="fullcontent"> 3
    <div class="fullcontent--prev">Prev</div>
    <div class="fullcontent--next">Next</div>
  </div>

  <div class="fullcontent"> 4
    <div class="fullcontent--prev">Prev</div>
    <div class="fullcontent--next">Next</div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
index = 1;
$('div.fullcontent').click(function(){  
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('div.fullcontent:eq('+index+')').offset().top
  }, 1000, 'easeInOutSine');
  index++;
  if(index>3)
  index=0;
  console.log(index);
})
```

Try this code you will get expected result

https://jsfiddle.net/y10dqh4q/